# Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, linux, installation, centos

When install **MySQL** in **Cent OS**, it is installed correctly.

After installation,I type this command in terminal.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

It shown error and I typed password as **'new-password'**. In this time, I found this error.

```
[root@datsvr018 bin]# /etc/init.d/mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]

[root@datsvr018 bin]# mysql_secure_installation

NOTE: RUNNING ALL PARTS OF THIS SCRIPT IS RECOMMENDED FOR ALL MySQL
      SERVERS IN PRODUCTION USE!  PLEASE READ EACH STEP CAREFULLY!

In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current password
for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and you haven't set
the root password yet, the password will be blank, so you should just press enter here.

Enter current password for root (enter for none): 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Comment: Hi, have you managed to resolve this issue somehow? I have the exact same problem

Comment: No, I am not doing with this anymore. At that time, I use the other OS(means windows) for my testing because I can't fix it. I found this issuse when research. If you find any solution, please post under this. I will vote for it. It will be helpful for other. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Right after install MySQL, you need to run `mysqladmin` to set root password.

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Comment: I uninstall MySQL and install again.After installation finished,I try.The errors are equal.